# Working with mongodb from Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I have launch mongodb server:

```
[demas@arch.local.net][~]% mongod --dbpatmongod --dbpath /home/demas/temp/  
Mon Apr 19 09:44:18 Mongo DB : starting : pid = 4538 port = 27017 dbpath = /home/demas/temp/ master = 0 slave = 0  32-bit 

** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
**       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations for more

Mon Apr 19 09:44:18 db version v1.4.0, pdfile version 4.5
Mon Apr 19 09:44:18 git version: nogitversion
Mon Apr 19 09:44:18 sys info: Linux arch.local.net 2.6.33-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 5 05:57:38 UTC 2010 i686 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Mon Apr 19 09:44:18 waiting for connections on port 27017
Mon Apr 19 09:44:18 web admin interface listening on port 28017
```

I have created documents by console client:

```
[demas@arch.local.net][~]% mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.4.0
url: test
connecting to: test
type "help" for help
> db.some.find();
 { "_id" : ObjectId("4bcbef3c3be43e9b7e04ef3d"), "name" : "mongo" }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("4bcbef423be43e9b7e04ef3e"), "x" : 3 }
```

Now I am trying to work with MongoDb from Java:

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Start");

        try {
        Mongo m = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = m.getDB("test");

        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("some");

        coll.insert(makeDocument(10, "James", "male"));
        System.out.println("Finish");
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MongoException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public static BasicDBObject makeDocument(int id, String name, String gender) {
        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
        doc.put("id", id);
        doc.put("name", name);
        doc.put("gender", gender);
        return doc;
    }
 }
```

But execution stops on line coll.insert():

```
 [demas@arch.local.net][~/dev/study/java/mongodb]% javac test1.java
 [demas@arch.local.net][~/dev/study/java/mongodb]% java test1      
 Start
```

There are not messages from mogodb server regarding accepted connection. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm...

If I change the line:

```
Mongo m = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
```

to:

```
Mongo m = new Mongo();
```

all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change localhost to `127.0.0.1`. May be it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /etc/hosts file to make sure that localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1.

Typically, it will contain a line like:

127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost